# Bootstrap 3 Effects div scrollover

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 as part of a web design and am wondering how to do something relatively simple but want to ensure it is done in the correct manner:

So I have an example of divs which cover 100% of the screen an any given time - but the top one will need to remain fixed at the top of the screen and the second div onwards will need to scroll on top and over it including any text on the first div.

I am needing some assistance eon the best way to achieve this.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WArb4/)

```
    html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
#imgDiv {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(http://wallpapershd3d.com/wp-content/gallery/hd-wallpapers/cute-parrots-hd-wallpaper.jpg);
}

#imgDiv2 {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(http://wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/digital-wallpaper-17.jpg);
}

<div id='imgDiv'></div>
<div id='imgDiv2'></div>
```

Comment: are you referring to parallax? like http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/ ?

Comment: @Ravimallya I guess I am yeah but it dosnt need to be so complex and was wondering how to achieve the desired effect of the top div remaining fixed and everything below scroll as you wold expect over the top of the div?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: @dschazam - So if you imagine the top div of my webpage 100% in height of the browser window with a block of text on it. Any content below so a second, third, fourth div would then scroll over the top of that top div inclusive of its contents, does that make sense?

Comment: This sound pretty much like parallax to me, as Ravi said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply apply `position:fixed` to the first `div` and give it `width:100%` whilst giving the second `div` an offset to its `top` of `100%`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/WArb4/1/)

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
#imgDiv {
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-image:url(http://wallpapershd3d.com/wp-content/gallery/hd-wallpapers/cute-parrots-hd-wallpaper.jpg);
}
#imgDiv2 {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    top:100%;
    background-image:url(http://wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/digital-wallpaper-17.jpg);
}
```